# why rxjava Observable.subscribe(observer) return void?

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

When I'm using Observable.subscribe() normally returns Disposable.

But Observable.subscribe(Observer) returns void.

So I can't dispose to Observable.subscribe(Observer).

According to introtorx.com Observable.subscribe(Obeserver) returns Disposable.

Why are rx and rxjava different?

++++++++++++++

I use `compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'` in Android Studio.

github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/Observable.java#L10831

```
public final void subscribe(Observer<? super T> observer) {
  ... 
}
```

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0owg1.png][1]

[[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7H4av.jpg][2]

Answer (score 3):

It's probably because of the Reactive Stream contract.

[Reactive Stream README](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm/blob/v1.0.0/README.md)

```
public interface Publisher<T> {
    public void subscribe(Subscriber<? super T> s);
}
```

The interface of `Publisher` is defined return void. RxJava `Flowable` implements that interface. And RxJava `Observable` follow that contract as well.

So they provide a `subscribeWith()` to return you a `Disposable` instead of void. Or you can use those overload method which can give you back a disposable too ex: `subscribe(consumer<T>,consumer<Throwable>,action)`

PS: above its my guess. I'm not sure of it.

Comment: Confirmed. You can read more [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#subscriber) and [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44640844/subscribewith-vs-subscribe-in-rxjava2android).

Answer (score 1):

In RxJava2, Disposable object is passed to Observer's onSubscribe call back method. You can get hold of Disposable object from onSubscribe call back method and use it to dispose the subscription at later point of time after subscribing the observer to observable.

Comment: That's correct, but unfortunately you don't always have access to implement or override the `Observer#onSubscribe` method.
For example, my current problem is that I have `PublishSubject` as an `Observer`, and I cannot override its `#onSubscribe`.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of `RxJava` do you use? With RxJava2 (`io.reactivex.rxjava2`):

```
public abstract class Observable<T> implements ObservableSource<T> {
  ...
  public final Disposable subscribe() {...}
  ...
}
```

Comment: i use compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1' on AndroidStudio

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/Observable.java
  public final void subscribe(Observer<? super T> observer) {
...
}

Comment: Ho right! It's because `Observer` receive the `Disposable` in `onSubscribe(...)`. You have to use `Consumer` instead.